# Do we want accepted answers unpinned on Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Stack Overflow changed the way they sort answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/outdated-answers-accepted-answer-is-now-unpinned-on-stack-overflow):

> We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

and it is asked on Meta Stack Exchange if [we would like to have the accepted answer unpinned on our site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers):

> We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings. We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site. ... We are going to collect feedback before the end of September 19th.

I am posting this here so that we can have a discussion of what is best for the Mathematics Stack Exchange site.

**Update:**

Based on the voting and the [report on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369913/196432), the site setting [has been adjusted to *not* pinning accepted answers on Math.SE anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/196432):

> There's no need to do this on the sites that are on the list already; we have adjusted the site setting for them.

Comment: Judging by the edits, the real question is whether we are MSE, math.se, or Math.SE.

Comment: A soft option (at least in theory) would be to make the ✅ count for some $K\ge 1$ upvotes, say $K=5$. Then early on, the accepted answer will be up top, but if a newer answer can prove itself, it will beat the accepted answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sir I think Math.SE   is the right word

Comment: Yes to the question posed in title.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is an interesting idea.  I suggest that you follow up on Meta SE about it.  However, the *current* state of affairs is that we have binary option:  (1) leave things the way they are (accepted answers are unpinned, all answers are sorted by score), or (2) request that the SE overlords pin accepted answers.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: As I understand it, we have three options: (1) have accepted answers pinned to the top, (2) have answers sorted by votes, or (3) do nothing and accept the global default (and it is not decided yet which one that is).

Comment: @MartinR This may be nitpickery, but I see basically two options:  either pin accepted answers, or don't pin them.  Giving an accepted answer a +5 is not one of the possible options.  I think that my reference to defaults may have been a distraction.

Comment: If accepted answers are unpinned, then what's the point of the whole "accepted answer" concept?

Comment: If we choose one thing now and sometime later decide we don't like it, can we change it?

Comment: @PeterPhipps: As I understand it from https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/196432 it is a “site setting” and I *assume* that our moderators can have it changed. I do not know what the proper procedure is, though, probably a new discussion on Meta.

Comment: "If accepted answers are unpinned, then what's the point of the whole "accepted answer" concept?"  Per a comment I left below my own answer, accepting an answer is a way for a user to say "thank you" and award a small bounty.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sure, but that doesn't have to be done publicly. Either the green tick does not convey any information of use to future readers, so removing it entirely makes sense, or it does convey useful information. I don't see the point of the "keep it, but don't pin it" middle ground. (I really like Calvin's suggested middle ground though.)

Comment: @user1729 Do you have a similar objection to bounties?

Comment: @XanderHenderson If you mean the blue mark beside an answer which has been awarded a bounty, then yes, my logic applies there too. Either it conveys no information of use to future readers, but then why keep it, or it useful. (For what it is worth, I think both the green tick and the blue box *do* convey useful information, and should be treated like they do. As I said, I like Calvin's suggestion.)

Comment: Okay, so, again:  the green check mark can be thought of *exactly* as a bounty is thought of.  It is a way for one user (the original asker, in this case) to say "Your answer is the one I though was most useful".

Comment: @Xander Yes, but then so what? As I said, my logic applies to the check mark beside bounties too. Either the checkmark is useful and we acknowledge this somehow, or it is not. Your answer seems to advocate that it is *not* useful to future users, so then why have it at all?

Comment: @user1729 No, you are misinterpreting what I have written.  I have not said that the green check is not useful for future readers.  I have stated that I think vote totals are more relevant than the green check.  My feeling is that the green check should be treated exactly as a bounty:  it creates a visible flag on the post, which draws attention to it, and it rewards the answerer with a small amount of XP.  Neither bounties nor the green check should be used (by default) for ordering the presentation of answers.

Comment: @CalvinKhor We literally honour those who provide *significantly* better answers than the accepted one: the **Populist** badge. That could be a guidance as to which answers should be placed above the accepted one.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist The status- tags are mostly used that the level of the SE overlords for tracking bugs, feature requests, etc.  As this post is a "discussion" (not a bug report or feature request), I am not sure that the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag is entirely appropriate.  We can still discuss this, after all.

Comment: What happens by default now if you answer a question that already has answers?  Will your answer get buried under the other answers?

Comment: @RandomVariable Nothing has changed, except that the "accepted" answer is no longer pinned to the top.  For users who use the default sorting, a new answer to an old question will likely sit at the bottom of the page (unless there are answers with negative scores).  Of course, other sorting preferences are available (active, oldest, votes).

Comment: @XanderHenderson If you were signed into your account, I thought the default way of sorting answers was by activity.  I guess I must have changed that setting years ago.

Comment: It's funny that you accepted an answer. How ironic.

Comment: @NikeDattani: Why do you think so? I accepted the answer because it has by far the most votes, and because the suggestion “sort by number of votes only” has been implemented for Math.SE by the site moderators. – This poll was not about whether to accept answers or not.

Comment: @MartinR The site setting has been changed to “unpin” only for the main site, not for the meta site. For instance, see any of the posts that turn up in this SEDE query: [Questions with accepted answer pinned above highest scoring answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1458833/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer).

Comment: In particular, see the comments under the linked Meta SE question. “Can you clarify whether this change will affect local child metas as well, and whether the setting can be different on the main site and its meta (i.e. pin on meta but not on main or vice versa)?” – 
ACuriousMind. “Site settings are per-site and, yes, child metas are considered a "site". :)” – 
Catija.

Comment: So, in case we want to have the setting changed to “unpin” on the meta site as well, then I guess we need to first open a new Meta discussion regarding this and once again establish a consensus. At least one site (Ask Ubuntu) has had separate discussions regarding the unpinning on their main and meta site.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: You are completely right. I *thought* that I had observed the "unpinning" also on Math Meta, but apparently I am wrong.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: It [seems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/196432) that "Ask Ubuntu" and "Politics" are the only sites who discussed this for their meta site.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

(Note:  this is my opinion as a user; my moderator hat is off.)

**I am in favor of ordering answers by number of votes only.**

The green check is supposed to indicate that the author of the question found a particular answer more useful than others.  It has been my observation that many question authors here (a) lack the mathematical maturity to judge a "good" answer, and (b) are inclined to give the green check to the first person who answers.  As such, a lot of the accepted answers on Math SE are not as good as alternative answers.

Assuming that my anecdotal observations of the state of the site are correct, I think that it makes sense to order answers strictly by number of votes, and to ignore the green check.

Comment: (This is here as an answer rather than a comment so that it can attract both upvotes and downvotes.)

Comment: On a fence about this. Your description is accurate in many cases, and that sorting works better than the current. Against that there are cases like my second highest voted answer. It has more votes than the accepted answer, but *it is building upon it*. I just wanted to explain the observed phenomena a bit more, and the voters liked it better. Yet, the frequencies are probably on your side. My answer does refer to the accepted answer, so the readers should not be mislead too much, if their order is changed.

Comment: One reason I agree with this answer is that it helps a wee bit to de-incentivize the FGITW: (the fastest guns in the west), who manage to pounce to answer, and do so in a very short period of time (though often, they continue to edit... and edit, and...).  And I think, in that sense, it may give merit to those who think carefully, take there time to craft a very good answer, and post,often with little need to edit.  I actually think it helps level the "playing field" in terms of answering.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is definitely a "rich get richer" problem, but if there is any consistent presentation of answers, that is going to be a problem.  Either the accepted answer accumulates extra votes because it is on top, or the already most-upvoted answer accumulates more votes.  Hard to say what is right.

Comment: How do you propose to break ties, Xander?

Comment: It really depends on how the site is "perceived". If the goal is to have good questions and good answers useful to as many people as possible, then clearly it's better to sort by vote, and we don't even care that the OP has accepted an answer. If we try first to answer questions of people who have a problem, then accepting an answer is an important feedback, and it should always be the first answer. For instance, there are case where the most upvoted answers don't take into account some constraints in the question, yet they are very good answers with another approach, hence the votes.

Comment: The caricatural description: is MSE a curated FAQ, where some questions don't deserved to be answered, and don't even deserved to stay here, or is it more a "let me help you" service, where no question is too dumb? I believe there are regular users out here on both sides of this, and anywhere in between. It's not really a secret that I'm more on the "let me help you" side, but it's my natural way of thinking, and I'm also a public servant.

Comment: There's a major leap of logic from "acceptance is important feedback" to "accepted answers should always be on top". How does knowing a solution helped one specific user, make it most helpful to later readers? And if it has been accepted, it must have been read and used by the acceptor, meaning it doesn't need to be pinned at the top for them. So what therefore is the point of pinning any answer at all, much less on the basis of it being helpful to one specific person?

Comment: @Nij That's the point, it's mainly helpful to those who will answer the OP to have a better idea of his level/expectations. However, if he has already selected an answer, the question is usually settled (not *always*). As I said, if the goal is to be helpful to has many readers as possible, there is no point in even requiring the OP to select an answer, as nobody cares. It's only relevant at the initial step (exchanges between the OP and current and future respondents). I tend to agree with this answer (and I did upvote). My point was that it's usually all about short term/long term viewpoint.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am in a camp that doesn't see a lot of value in the green check.  I think that it might have some value on a site like SO, where the original asker can say "Yup, the code works now and does the thing I want it to do", but I think it has much less value here.  I have come to understand the green check as a "bounty" which the original asker as the privilege of awarding.  It is an extra "thank you" from the post author, and has little significance beyond that.

Comment: I agree. I would go further: voting is useful: the community decides which answer is best, in a rather democratic process (that's also debatable in maths, but it's better than the alternatives, on a web site). However, reputation points are not very useful: apart from the self esteem boost, they are only helpful in deciding if a user can be trusted or not. But actually reputation points tell nothing about the ability of the respondent on that particular subject (for instance, I may answer on numerical analysis or calculus, but I'm a noob in algebraic topology). The tag badges are more relevant

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  One problem with your thinking, that I see, that it is *precisely "useful votes"* that afford some more rep than others.  And badges depend on net upvotes on an appropriate number of posts within a tag.  So your dichotomy is not a dichotomy, sorry.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Neither can you honestly claim to be  "merely a servant to the community", else you'd choose Community Wiki for all your answers.

Comment: @amWhy Note that all my answers >20 upvotes are community wiki. And I don't see how votes on a question are necessarily linked to user rep. It's a design choice, note a necessity. And FYI I am a public servant, in real life (I thought it was obvious enough that I didn't have to add that precision). But why are you really arguing, anyway?

Comment: I'm just saying that on SE, reputation, as a matter of fact, is directly related to the votes one receives on one's answers (albeit, not on CW posts).  I never argued that they *must be related*, just that on this site, they are, de facto, interdependent.  Interesting, because my question is precisely, why are you arguing?

Comment: I know that. And to me it's a burden. Votes on answers, why not. badges, why not. Reps? Only really useful to inlock site features. Besides, mathematical statements are not more correct because of the reputation of their author - and when I read maths, here or elsewhere, I don't care very much about the author's reputation, only the quality of what he has written. And I don't think I was arguing, but guess what, I'm not surprised. *Once his fault, twice my fault*, as they say.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did not see your comment until now.  My understanding is that, on a per-site basis, we have two options:  (1) order posts strictly on the basis of net votes, or (2) order posts on the basis of net votes, but put accepted answers at the top.  These are (or will be) the only options available network wide.  A more nuanced discussion of how answers are ordered is not going to be fruitful here, as we don't have any per-site ability to change these settings.  However, you might have a fruitful discussion of this on the main meta site.

Comment: [E.g. it has already been suggested that the green check be used as a tie-breaker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369569/436415)

Comment: When I first got here I was surprised and a bit annoyed this kind of atmosphere where people focus more on making the answer general than actually helping the person asking the question.  Accusing the questioner of "lacking the mathematical maturity to judge a good answer" is just stupid. *The main goal of an answer should be to provide the **questioner** with an answer they can understand and make use of*. If you write a mathematically mature answer that the questioner does not understand YOU HAVE FAILED.

Comment: @ContraKinta I would invite you to adopt a more civil tone.  Calling others "stupid" is a violation of the SE Code of Conduct.

Comment: Responding to the substance of your comment:  I do not think that the issue is that answerers are writing "mathematically mature answer that the questioner does not understand".  Rather, I think that a lot of questions get (1) quick answers with a short computation that can be turned in as homework, and (2) longer answers which attempt to explain *why* something is true.  The former is often accepted quickly because (1) it provides the asker with what they wanted (homework help), and (2) it came quickly.  However, an answer which provides explanation is better for the site on the whole.

Comment: I am also somewhat shocked at the level of vitriol on display here.  We are talking about a site setting which would change the order in which answers are presented.  We are not talking about closing questions, deleting content, or suspending accounts.  We are discussing whether or not the "accepted answer" should be displayed first, or if the most highly upvoted answer should be displayed first (assuming that these are not the same).  I don't think that it is a huge deal in either direction---perhaps we can continue the conversation with civility?

Comment: Finally, because I reread the comment:  the main goal of the SE network is **not** to provide the questioner with an answer.  The main goal of the SE network is to connect questioners with answers (see [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/); search for the text "inverted pyramid" to get to the relevant bit).  If an individual asker is helped, excellent!  But helping future askers is even more important.  Votes reflect how useful *other* readers have found an answer, including these important future askers.

Comment: First of all, I have not called anyone stupid. I said  *Accusing the questioner of  lacking the mathematical maturity to judge a good answer* is stupid. You are putting words in my mouth. Secondly, stuff like "*the main goal of the SE network is not to provide the questioner with an answer.* " is really off putting. Especially if the end result is an incentive to write answers that will rather please the mathematically mature audience of registered regulars rather than helping the actual questioner and all the registered/unregistered people on his or her level of mathematical maturity.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The concern with the voting system you propose, as I see from what Contrakinta is saying, is that if people see that questions are ordered by votes, they will not necessarily want to write for the OP, but rather for the general audience (on occasions where they know that a general audience will appreciate their answer more than an OP e.g. with a generalization). This should not lead to the preferred objective of an answer being to address a general audience rather than the OP itself. We have to preserve both objectives, and I don't think disregarding the green check is correct

Comment: In my opinion, the main goal of an answer is to be able to write *both* for the OP, as well as for the general population. This is at least what I strive to do. I get the feeling that this suggestion completely disregards OPs opinion of the answers they received as null and void : yes, maybe the majoritarian questioner behaviour is of the kind mentioned, but I don't think the situation is so bad that we must bin the value of the green check mark. It should count : I'd go with what Calvin says ideally , but in a forced situation i.e. the binary, I'd agree with you.

Comment: I'm also on a bit of a fence regarding the "main goal" comment. When I write an answer I'd try to please OP because I think they are the "average" person coming to me with the question they have posed, and so presume that the audience that is reading the question is on average at the level of OP. I don't know how to write for the public, but I assume that OP is an "average" member of the public asking their question, and so write an answer as the OP wants it (and maybe for a population of higher understanding). Point being : OP's contribution should be valued more than this answer provides.

Comment: @Teresa I agree. Frequently, “in the particular, lies the universal” (James Joyce), and a customised Answer is more resonant than one that overlooks the OP to appeal to a general audience, whatever that means. We are after all addressing genuine Questions (which I find meaningful), and no one minds if an Answer goes into more details or generality than requested, or—if there already are multiple Answers—offers alternate perspectives. My position is to unpin, but not to to otherwise devalue, the Green Tick; eg., to give it priority over other Answers with the same vote-score.

Comment: I really don't understand a lot of the conversation happening here.  We have a binary choice:  either (1) sort answers by vote totals alone, or (2) sort answers by vote totals, but put the "accepted answer" on top.  I don't see anyone arguing that the green check has zero value, or that we should ignore the green check.  I don't see anyone arguing that the original asker should not be addressed (indeed, the green check indicates that their issue has been solved).  This is really only a question of how the information is presented to future readers, by default.

Comment: Given the binary option which has been presented to us, my feeling is that the default option should be to list answers only by total vote score.  If you feel that the binary choice is not good enough, e.g. you want to give the green check the power of $n$ upvotes, then please have this discussion in the [main meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers), where your suggestion has a chance of being heard.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'll summarize : I hate the binary nature of the situation from the bottom of my heart (and I believe that the order of display of answers should , in Calvin's way ideally, reflect the OP's decision to pick the "best" answer), but I'll go with your decision based on your statistics.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It is fine to be frustrated by the binary nature of the choice, but there is nothing that can be done about that in *this* forum.  If you want to make further suggestions, please join the conversation on the main meta (linked in the original post).  (Or, indeed, ways of giving accepted answers more weight have [already been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369636/436415).)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I accept that the choice is binary. In that case, I will vote in your favour, +1.

Comment: There are times where a higher voted answer is not as intuitive as the accepted answer. In that way, the second answer acts as a more rigorous expansion upon the first, which gets the idea across. However, I think on average, sorting by votes has more benefit for *future* questions.

Comment: I think you should remove the phrase "(Note: this is my opinion as a user; my moderator hat is off.)", since you use this post in Meta S.E, and speak as though you represent the MSE community through the votes given on this post. As a moderator of Math S.E., people will take your Meta S.E. post seriously, and thus I think it fair to remove the disclaimer at the start, and mention the cross post instead. (1 of 2)

Comment: You might wonder what difference does it make, but people currently are unaware of what their votes are contributing too, and some may simply upvote it because it is a well reasoned argument (with premises they may still disagree with). (2 of 2)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I agree wholeheartedly with your plea for civility. However the following is categorically not correct: "***We are discussing whether or not the "accepted answer" should be displayed first, or if the most highly upvoted answer should be displayed first (assuming that these are not the same). I don't think that it is a huge deal in either direction*** In the current system, highly upvoted  (often just early) answers appear under the accepted one. The accepted one is merely an inconvenience if inferior. (cont)

Comment: @XanderHenderson However, now, late and helpful answers will be buried under a heap of mediocre answers, unread by hundreds of thousand users who might benefit from them. Mathematics is just about to banish thousands of its most helpful and useful posts to obscurity. The general quality of this site is about to substantially deteriorate.

Comment: Downvoting because I disagree, not because I think that the answer is a bad one.

Answer (score 30):

I dislike this proposition, for one reason: For many questions, the highest voted answer is simply the oldest.  This is especially true of questions that appear on the "Hot Network Questions" list.  In such cases, often a really good answer will appear later and will never attain the same number of upvotes as earlier questions.  The "accepted answer" in this case can highlight such really good answers, distinguishing them from a plethora of mediocre, earlier ones.

The argument for unpinning accepted answers is to address situations where the highest upvoted answer is better than the accepted one.  However, my own experience since first starting to use stackexchange is that you learn quickly to always check the accepted *and* the most upvoted answers.  On the other hand, in the reverse situation where an answer is accepted to highlight it among a throng of highly upvoted answers, if the accepted answer is unpinned, there remains no way to make such an answer more visible.

I have personally had several of my answers be accepted, and only well after acceptance did they reach the status of most upvoted.  I think unpinning will cause a greater problem than it solves by effectively preventing this from happening.

Comment: Given how late I am in responding to this question, I wonder if this answer will suffer the same fate I describe, of not being visible for long enough to attain to the other answers...

Comment: I think this answer makes a very valid point. Unfortunately, [Xander has already said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369913#369913) that "Mathematics SE is in favour of unpinning accepted answers", and so it does seem a little too late. This is why I would have preferred it if each individual user can choose how they the answers.

Comment: This is a good point, that if you want to see both the top vote-getter and the accepted answer, then you can just look at the top two (by default) as it is now, but it won't be so easy to look for the accepted answer if we change it.  It may be too late, but I think that I want to change my vote now!

Comment: I have the same personal experience (i.e. late answer that gets accepted but few votes initially). However, I still agree with Xander's view because: (1) this is rare; (2) **usually** Math SE users who are not drive-by voters from the untrained HNQ crowd identify wrong answers that the asker cannot. Since there is a strong effect of biasing future voters toward the top answers, allowing a bad answer to stay on top by mere virtue of being 'accepted' is quite unacceptable.

Comment: Hey, Maarten here, mod from [crypto.se]. I think this is a big problem with [se] and Q/A sites in general. But usually the accepted answer is also very old, so in that sense the reordering won't make much of a difference. It would only work if the org. poster changed the accept to a better / newer answer, but that's highly unlikely to happen in my experience. And a great accepted answer will still have the nice green mark beside it to distinguish it from the crowd.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's what everyone says, but all the SEDE queries seem to show that in fact accepted answers are more likely to be later answers. The mathematics is against you! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Interesting stats, I'll remember that.

Comment: I totally agree to this answer. Thanks for posting another view to the question. I think there are many users (majority?) have the same opinion. I gave up for a long time to comprehend the voting- and listing-system here on MSE.

Answer (score 15):

I think the best solution would be to allow users to choose between sorting strictly by the number of votes, and putting the accepted answer at the top. Right now, there are three ways of sorting the answers: active, oldest, and votes. I would like to add a fourth option that ignores whether an answer has been accepted or not. (What this option should be called is another question.) As before, the site should "remember" the option that you used last time.

Comment: The biggest impact of sorting on this site is how answers are presented to users who likely don't have accounts here, or who have very young accounts, and are not aware of the fact that posts can be sorted.  For anyone who has already figured out that they can rearrange posts, I have no objection to a "strictly votes" vs "check, then votes" option, but I think that this is somewhat orthogonal to the real issue, which is about default presentation.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I agree that the default presentation is an important issue that we need to discuss (personally, I haven't been convinced either way), but I also think that the point I'm making is relevant. Stack Overflow removed the option to put the accepted answer first, and I can't think of any reason why that would be better than just allowing users to choose how they want to sort posts.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as posed here. Math SE will have a choice of yes-pin or no-pin. Feedback on what other settings could be used belong on the Meta SE post, where they can be actioned or discarded, not here, where they just add noise to what could be a complicated enough discussion just in the yes/no part

Comment: "Feedback on what other settings could be used belong on the Meta SE post" - Technically, the Meta Stack Exchange post *also* asks what the default behavior should be on the rest of the network besides SO: should accepted answers be unpinned network-wide, or not? ...It's just that many people have left feature requests there anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Yup I want accepted answers to be unpinned. However as I wrote my decision in meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369569/1052107) I would like that if 2 or more answers have same score out of which one is accepted then that accepted should be upper than the remaining other answers having same score.

Also it would be of immense pleasure if  a user himself has the preference option in settings to choose whether in his question he want the accepted answer to be pinned or not.

Answer (score -11):

## Tl;dr:

- *In Theory:* **Yes**
- *In Practice:* **No**

---

## In Theory

In theory, as we know, posts should be voted according to their quality so that visitors can find the best ones easily.

So, when some answers are provided to a question, the best ones should be placed at the top of the answer list to help readers of the thread find more useful answers.

However, the questioner may accept some answer according to their need and understanding of the subject of the post; it is clear that such a choice does not necessarily indicate the best answer.

Thus, in theory, I agree that accepted answers should be unpinned.

## In Practice

In practice, as we know **well**, poster are often voted, *not their posts*. Let us recall the following [community misbehavior](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33184/downvoting-posts-that-are-very-popular-but-not-especially-good-is-this-an-acce#comment149883_33184) concerning the issue:

> Questions are illigiitmately upvoted for reasons unrelated to the quality of a question. A very poor post answered by 5 separate users may very well get five upvotes. Friends upvote friends, admire certain users, etc.

(Although this a harsh but **irrefutable** fact, I think ignoring/evading it would not help us to find the best solutions for our community **at all**.)

Although such abuse may happen in acceptance of answers, its occurrence rate is likely much lower than that of post voting.

So, not to mislead people, especially novice users, it is **strongly** recommended **not** to implement the feature request until some people change their behavior.

Comment: -1: Quoting one random comment and call it "community norm" is ridiculous.

Comment: You are making some rather extraordinary claims here.  Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  What evidence do you have that (1) votes are based on who posted something, rather than the content of a post? and (2) that this is a "community norm"?

Comment: It is also interesting that you truncated the comment you quoted.  The full quote is (the omitted portion is bolded): "Questions are illigiitmately upvoted for reasons unrelated to the quality of a question. A very poor post answered by 5 separate users may very well get five upvotes. Friends upvote friends, admire certain users, etc. **To me those are abuses in voting far more often that retaliatory downvotes.**"

Comment: @XanderHenderson What evidence would **satisfy** you? If I showed you that my inactive posts received some downvotes immediately after my participation on Meta, if I showed you many high quality posts having much less scores than low quality ones, if I showed you many people complaining about the issue on Meta or in other places, ... , then would you satisfy, or you would say that *the community* judged the quality of the posts by their own opinions? Even, you ignore some heavily upvoted comment from some experienced user. If we want to evade unpleasant clear issues, we will harm ourselves.

Comment: The claim that you are making now ("Sometimes I get downvotes after participating in Meta") is very different from the claim made in your post, above ("The community norm is that votes are cast for individuals, not based on the merit of posts").  Conflating the two is akin to suggesting that armed robbery is a community norm in the US because as a convenience store in East LA was robbed last night.  Votes which target individuals are *not* a community norm here, and are an **abuse** of the voting system.  We try very hard to crack down on that kind of behaviour.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, you are right. I confess that I was wrong; I should not have used that term. I edited the post.