# Sorting answers by last modified date gives peculiar results

Tags: support, answers, sorting

I was looking at [this question on Maths Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-copy-mixture-of-text-and-latex-formulas-in-a-comment?). There are four answers and I have them sorted by Date Modified (Newest First).

Listed below are the created and last modified dates of the four answers **in the order they are presented**.
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Creation date} &  \text{Last modified date} \\  
\hline
\text{2011-11-23}  & \text{2017-04-13} \\  
\text{2023-08-05}  & \text{Not yet modified} \\  
\text{2017-03-14}  & \text{2022-10-23} \\  
\text{2014-08-07}  & \text{2020-06-12}
\end{array}

In what sense are these sorted by last modified date? Or, How do I interpret this? It seems that the first one should be last.

The other two sort methods seem to work correctly, i.e. I get what I would expect to see.

Comment: With "Date Modified (Newest First)" if some answer is accepted it appears at the top.

Comment: Note that on main site the default is "Highest score" and there the accepted answer doesn't necessarily come at the top.

Comment: I didn't know that about accepted answers. Is it in the help pages?

Comment: See the relevant meta threads https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/432929 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34076/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, could you make your comment into an answer please? It is the correct answer and I'm unlikely to get anything else.