# What fraction of users gained the established user privilege over the years?

Tags: support, reputation, statistics, privileges

I want to know, out of all the users who joined MSE in a year, what amount of users gained the privilege of becoming an established user from one year of that account plotted as a function of time (unit=year).

Eg: Suppose someone made an account in 2019 November, and then in December 2020, they become 1k rep, then that is one count towards 2020 year.

Comment: This post is a [Response to a comment under this users meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34602/the-rep-requirement-for-privileges-should-be-reduced?noredirect=1#comment161240_34602), when asked for evidence to the accusations in the linked post.

Comment: I am actually astonished that this question was downvoted. Downvoters: What's wrong with the question? I am not sure how to do SDE queries, if I did, I'd have done it myself

Comment: I wonder how this piece of information should be interpreted. MSE had been growing, so the number of answerers and those getting >1000 are both increasing I suppose. How does the fraction imply anything?

Comment: This post reads like a request for someone else to write SEDE queries for you.  Meta is not really the right place for such a request.  You could try https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/martin-sleziaks-room , but this seems off-topic here.

Comment: You could also ask for help with SEDE queries on [meta.se].

Comment: And there is a site-agnostic [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede), too.

Comment: regarding learning how to use SEDE (which I have not) there is a tutorial [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239630/please-add-a-tutorial-for-sede)

Comment: more questions= more users= more answers, the reputation will be spread among all the new people answering. The question is, are the rates of new people gaining 1k rep privilege less or more than before? If it is less, then there can be a policy change.

Comment: Even if it is less, it might be that the fraction is not a good indicator.

Comment: "more questions= more users= more answers" Do you have any evidence to back up that assertion?  An equally compelling assertion is that more questions are being asked by more "newbie" users who create accounts to ask one or two questions, and then go away forever.  These users tend not to cast a lot of votes, and are not involved in the community, but they sure do generate a lot of mediocre content.

Comment: Hmm I think it is self evident. The newbie users thing, it does exist in parallel to what I've said, but the thing is that I'm guessing every year has it's share of newbie users behaving like so. I'm guessing that the effect you've mentioned is becoming less relevant with year as the community as a whole is becoming 'nicer' (see the different threads discussing community to be less toxic)..

Comment: Don't forget, Buraian; duplicates occur much more frequently than earlier: a significant portion of new questions, are questions already answered, which are closed as dupes, and sometimes, deleted, if they are simultaneously very low quality.  With more users come more reviewers, who can close, reopen, delete, edit, or flag, etc.  At the start of this site, there weren't so many users reviewing.

Comment: I mightve deleted the comment, but, the rate of duplicate close have actually been steady. @amWhy