# Why was this relevant comment under the meta question deleted?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

This meta question is asked recently:
[Why should this question asking the proof of a statement in a book be deleted?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34834/)

There was a highly relevant comment to the post:

[image]

But it is now deleted.

This comment is relevant to the meta discussion. There is nothing uncivil and I do not see any reason to delete it.

I do not think it is deleted by the commenter themselves.

Why should this comment be deleted?

Comment: Only parts of the comment is still relevant (about mentioning Cauchy's root test being some context). Otherwise it is obsolete: the image had been converted to text, and 6, but not 3 users had voted to delete.

Comment: "Questions that only a moderator can answer are off topic on meta." This is frankly ridiculous. I do not think there is such a rule in meta. "No user can delete another user's comment." But a user can flag and ask a moderator to delete other's comment.

Answer (score 6):

First, it should be noted that, even on Meta, comments are ephemeral, and are subject to deletion.  This is particularly true when discussion threads become very lengthy, or when they start to get heated.

In this particular case, I deleted the comment (along with about 20 others) because they were devolving into personal attacks and accusations, and were largely not relevant to the actual topic being discussed.  I deleted nearly the entire thread, and did not spend too much time trying to preserve specific comments.  This comment got caught up in the mass deleting.

In other words, that comment occurred in context with many other comments, all of which were part of an unproductive thread.  Asking about that comment in isolation ignores the broader context.